# Racing web request promises recursively

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have a web request that sometimes completes in .1 seconds, and sometimes completes in 20 seconds.
My solution is to send requests with a timeout. When the timeout triggers, I want to send another request.
However, I want to leave the previous request open, and race it against the new request.
I want to do this until one of the open requests completes, ending the race for all open requests.
I'm also open to suggestions for an alternative approach to this problem.

```
const timeoutLimit = 300;
const timeoutMessage = 'Response timed out';

/** Executes a request, retrying on timeouts, until it returns successfully. */
export default async function requestWithTimeout(request, count) {
  const timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject(timeoutMessage), timeoutLimit);
  });

  const apiCall = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request
      .catch((err) => reject(err))
      .then((resp) => resolve(resp));
  });

  count += 1;

  const result = await Promise.race([apiCall, timeout])
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err, count);
      return (err === timeoutMessage) ? Promise.race([apiCall, requestWithTimeout(request, count)]) : err;
    })
    .then((val) => {
      console.log('returned', count);
      return val;
    });

  console.log(count, result);

  return result;
}
```

Here is an example of the output from the console:
[print statements indicating timeout and response order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kP5Y.png)

I always get things printed in this order:

```
Response timed out 1
Response timed out 2
returned 1
returned 2
returned 3
data 1
data 2
data 3
```

But I want my response to be something like this:

```
Response timed out 1
Response timed out 2
returned 1
data 1
returned 3
data 3
returned 2
data 2
```

Comment: You're looking for something like Promise.any()?

Comment: I would use Promise.any() if I could periodically add promises to the list it evaluates, but I can't add promises to the list after I call it.

Comment: I get the same result if I just replace Promise.race() with Promise.any(), and try to add promises to it recursively.

Comment: Why not use a package like axios to make the requests? You can set the timeout in ms when sending each request. 
" `timeout` specifies the number of milliseconds before the request times out.
  // If the request takes longer than `timeout`, the request will be aborted."
https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll just try looping Axios requests with timeouts until one of them returns. I was hoping for a solution where I could keep the earlier requests open too, in case one of the them returned, but I don't think async recursion is going to work the way I want it to here.

Comment: You could use axios with Promise.any(). And potentially use cancelTokens to cancel the rest of the promises.

Comment: cancelTokens would be a good optimization for this, but I don't think Promise.any() would work better than Promise.race() here. My problem revolves around my inability to add promises to the list being evaluated by Promise.race(). I want to add another promise to the list of pending promises when the timeout period ends. In this way, I can build a list of concurrent requests that are racing each other, increasing the likelihood that one of the requests will be fulfilled by my server with an erratic response time.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use an array to keep track of pending promises. In this way, I can open a request, and race it against the previous, still pending requests that lost a race against a timeout promise. The races will end whenever one of the pending request promises is fulfilled. This will slowly build an array of requests every timeout period, until one of them is fulfilled. By slowly increasing the number of concurrent requests instead of discarding them after the timeout period, I want to increase the likelihood that one of the requests is fulfilled by my server with an erratic response time.

```
const timeoutLimit = 250;
const timeoutLimitMessage = 'Response timed out, retrying';
const requestLimit = 20;
const RequestLimitMessage = 'Too many requests';

/** Executes a request, retrying on timeouts, until it returns successfully. */
export default async function requestWithTimeout(request, promises = []) {
  const timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject(timeoutLimitMessage), timeoutLimit);
  });

  const apiCall = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request
      .catch((err) => reject(err))
      .then((resp) => resolve(resp));
  });

  promises.push(apiCall);

  const result = await Promise.race([...promises, timeout])
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err !== timeoutLimitMessage) {
        return err;
      }
      console.log(timeoutLimitMessage);
      if (promises.length > requestLimit) {
        throw new Error(RequestLimitMessage);
      }
      return Promise.race([...promises, requestWithTimeout(request, promises)]);
    })
    .then((resp) => resp);

  return result;
}
```